# Jaspersoft compiles as in Document is Empty a listing

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem when using the List in JasperSoft. Download the example from https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2012/10/22/jasper-report-j-r-bean-collection-data-source/?unapproved=20656&moderation-hash=fa6bdd0662e97c7ac35f251c43dc7ab2#comment-20656 and I did it on my own and it shows me 'The document is empty'.

Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.9.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.9.0-cb8f9004be492ccc537180b49c026951f4220bf3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="fichaEmpresa" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3e4ba309-c498-4e79-894a-7dc160ac7980">
 <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
 <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
 <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
 <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="c237071d-dee0-40ab-93f7-1582ae09e0e7">
     <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
 </subDataset>
 <parameter name="empleados" class="java.util.List">
     <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList("Jose Manuel Sánchez", "Alfonso Blanco", "Angel García", "Rubén Aguilera")]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <background>
     <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <title>
     <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
         <staticText>
             <reportElement x="14" y="23" width="198" height="33" uuid="05e0ed3e-9178-4d7e-b254-1e4c35c3d959"/>
             <textElement>
                 <font fontName="Serif" size="24"/>
             </textElement>
             <text><![CDATA[Autentia]]></text>
         </staticText>
         <line>
             <reportElement x="14" y="56" width="529" height="1" uuid="bfe3eb8b-813e-4a9a-8225-05ab3d95d003"/>
         </line>
     </band>
 </title>
 <detail>
     <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
         <componentElement>
             <reportElement x="15" y="39" width="400" height="24" uuid="a39b414d-307b-4530-a724-756f9ecebd28"/>
             <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                 <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1" uuid="22af81cb-5d7f-4610-8650-a76bc2c4d055">
                     <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{empleados})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                 </datasetRun>
                 <jr:listContents height="24" width="400">
                     <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                         <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="252" height="20" uuid="9e6fde46-3d0b-472d-a820-1783f897b332"/>
                         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                     </textField>
                 </jr:listContents>
             </jr:list>
         </componentElement>
         <staticText>
             <reportElement x="14" y="7" width="198" height="20" uuid="05e0ed3e-9178-4d7e-b254-1e4c35c3d959"/>
             <textElement>
                 <font fontName="Serif" size="16"/>
             </textElement>
             <text><![CDATA[Empleados]]></text>
         </staticText>
         <line>
             <reportElement x="15" y="26" width="529" height="1" uuid="bfe3eb8b-813e-4a9a-8225-05ab3d95d003"/>
         </line>
     </band>
 </detail>
 <pageFooter>
     <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
         <textField>
             <reportElement x="435" y="34" width="80" height="20" uuid="63866af7-3cf4-433d-9eea-38b66b5a54f9"/>
             <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                 <font fontName="Serif"/>
             </textElement>
             <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
         </textField>
         <textField evaluationTime="Report">
             <reportElement x="515" y="34" width="40" height="20" uuid="0093ca23-9734-4207-b22e-8b4161c0ab20"/>
             <textElement>
                 <font fontName="Serif"/>
             </textElement>
             <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
         </textField>
     </band>
 </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Your query returns no data. That's all we can tell you based on the info you've provided. And I don't like clicking links to some weird pages (never heard about that one)

Comment: But I have some data by default. Shouldn't you return that data?